# Video and Audio Chat Protocols/Frameworks

Tags: qt, networking

I've been doing some research in how to implement a server free, point-to-point video/audio chat (i.e., my own skype without text messaging).

I've been looking for ways to implement it and I had this next ideas:

1. A multithreaded c++ (cause I know some c++) program getting audio and video (with qt), sending it through 2 different UDP sockets and reading video and audio from 2 other different UDP sockets from the other 'point'. So I'll had to write the UDP server and client multithreaded with a sum of 4 threads: 2 for sending audio and video, other 2 to receive audio and video.
2. Writing my own protocol to enable video and audio in the same thread, something like parsing half of the packet data size for audio and video buffering, which would leave me with only 2 threads in the application and a lot more 'error prone' code to write.
3. I've been looking to some real time media protocols, and some of them looked interesting. Maybe study and implement interfaces to this protocols and use them instead of 'creating' my own.

Now, the actual question(s):

1. Are there some documentation on how to accomplish this? Maybe some 'state of the art' apis/protocols that are being used or well implemented/suited solutions for this problem?
2. If I choose to implement audio separated from video, is VoIP a possible solution to the audio connection?
3. Is Qt a good tool for this purpose? I never used Qt before, and for video and audio interfaces I also thought about openframeworks, so I was wondering if anyone has ever used one of this frameworks and if this is the right choice.

I know that my question has no code and that the range of possible answers is wide, but I really need some help here.

Thanks.

Comment: I am new in qt.  Did you get correct solution for audio & video chat in qt framework? i have same requirement. i tried googling for same but did not get any library for c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should answer on question: How your clients should connect / authorize without server part?

Notes: 1) Skype has servers. 2) A lot of internet users are visiting web throught NAT / Proxy.

Ofc, you can try to implement something for learning proposes, but if you want to create something usefull - try thirdparty solutions that are created by specialists. For example: google libjingle.

Comment: It is for learning purposes. I know that Skype has servers and that my app should have them too if I want to make it public, but, and at least for now, I just want to know the technology I need to study for this purpose. 
About libjingle, seems like a good framework, I didn't know it. Thanks a lot. 
And thanks a lot for your insight. Is the first time I start a bounty here just to get some attention. 
Could've done it the other way, but I hate duplicates :)

Comment: Your question couldn't be answered on one page. Creating such things - is a topic for books and require deep knowledge of networks / torrent topology. You may start to research libjingle source and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need VOIP library’s :)

There's no need to start from scratch you can use library’s opensource like: [opalvoip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opalvoip/)

Comment: can you suggest integration documentation for opalvoip because their site is pause? Thanks in advance.